# What is wrong with my docker-compose file

Tags: python, docker-compose

Can anybody help me to understand what is wrong with my docker-compose file:

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:latest
    container_name: postgres
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/postgressql/data 
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: docker 
    ports:
      - "5400:5432" 

  api:
    restart: always
    build: ./api
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    volumes: 
      - .:/api
    entrypoint: ["python3", "app.py"]

  parser:
    restart: always
    build: ./parser
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    volumes: 
      - .:/parser
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    entrypoint: ["python3", "run.py"]
volumes:
  db-data:
  api-data:
  parser-data:
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.8.5-buster
ENV APP_ROOT /src
RUN mkdir ${APP_ROOT}
WORKDIR ${APP_ROOT}}
ADD . ${APP_ROOT}
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip3 install -r ${APP_ROOT}/requirements.txt  
EXPOSE 8000
```

Terminal reply: parser_1    | python3: can't open file 'run.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

[My project tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/52znP.png)

Answer (score 1):

do the following inside your project folder to find the relative path of your run.py:

```
find . -name 'run.py' -printf "%P\n"
```

then take that result and update the entrypoint in your docker file:

```
 entrypoint: ["python3", "relative_filepath_from_find_command_above_goes_here"]
```

Comment: due to this method got path, but received: python3: can't open file 'parser/run.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory (

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, everything is working!

Answer (score 0):

You haven't mapped your local files to your *parser* container with `volume:` like you did in other services.
`No such file or directory`, it can't be found in your container.

EDIT:
This is a simple example I've made with 3 files:

```
# Dockerfile
FROM python:3.7
RUN mkdir /app
COPY ./test.py /app
WORKDIR  /app
```

```yaml
# docker-compose.yml
version: "3.7"
services:
    parser:
        build: .
        restart: always
        ports:
          - 8000:8000
        entrypoint: ["python3", "test.py"]
```

```py
# test.py
print("ok")
```

Comment: Revised it but problem still the same: no such file...

Comment: revised:

  `parser:
    restart: always
    build: ./parser
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    volumes: 
      - .:/parser
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    entrypoint: ["python3", "run.py"]

volumes:
  db-data:
  api-data:
  parser-data:`

Comment: Are you copying that run.py in the build process? I'll edit my post with a simple example I was testing.

Comment: Leo, sorry, I'm newbie in coding and did not quite understand your question(

Comment: No problem! :) Have you seen the example I've included in my answer?

Comment: Yes, I got it. Thanks a lot. I'll revise my code and revert with result tomorrow. Thank you

Comment: Ok! Also, if it still doesn't work, try putting this in the first line of your python script: `#!/usr/bin/env python`

Comment: Leo, thanks a lot. I'm happy, everything is working!!